# In MySql Accessing Multiple Tables in a single where command

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

In MySql query, I am Accessing multiple tables by a single where case like shown below query.

```
select  Type,count(*) as Count
    from  Equipment as eq,Manager as m,Holder as e
    where  m.PARENTID=e.ID
      AND  e.holderType='rich'
      AND  eq.ID=m.ID
    group by  Type;
```

I am getting output but i don't know this is the right way to do this. Is this a correct way to do this or not?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What is the difference between that comma and JOIN. is comma not doing the same work as JOIN ?

Comment: . . *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Whenever you have more than one table/subquery, you should be thinking "how am I going to be combining these".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your response. will use JOIN :)

Comment: The commajoin is less clear to the reader, though can provide equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use single where clause for accessing multiple tables

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is the preferred way for accessing multiple tables. Use a JOIN type that matches your requirement and use the ON clause on which the tables should be joined.

Example

```
SELECT  Type,count(*) as Count
    FROM  Equipment as eq
    LEFT JOIN  Manager as m  ON eq.ID=m.ID
    LEFT JOIN  Holder as e  ON m.PARENTID=e.ID
      AND  e.holderType='rich'
    GROUP BY  Type;
```

Comment: @Praveen Thanks bro :)